# IDEA Jetty remote debug problem. I wanna debug the war files in webapps folder

Tags: java, jetty

I successfully connected to the remote jvm server, but I can only debug the start.jar.
I extracted the war files at webapps folder and the breakpoint is useless.
How can I debug the web code?
Btw without maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file `${jetty.base}/modules/remote-debug.mod` with a variation of what you need for remote debug (different configuration for port or suspend?) ...

```
[exec]
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9999
```

Then when you want debug just add the command line `--module=remote-debug` to your `start.jar` execution and the remote debug will be used for just that execution.

Then it's just a matter of you starting a remote debug session in your IDE against the same configuration.

Comment: I directly  add ```-Xdebug xxxx``` as java process commandline. Is there any difference? I still cannot set breakpoint at war files.

Comment: Yes, as the start.jar can fork the JVM very easily on Jetty 9.  It is recommended to use this module approach to be sure the debug is set on the correct JVM. See https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7299